# How can I interweave items from two arrays?

Tags: ruby, iterable

How can I go from this:

```
for number in [1,2] do
    puts 1+number
    puts 2+number
    puts 3+number
end
```

which will return `2,3,4` then `3,4,5 -> 2,3,4,3,4,5`. This is just an example, and clearly not the real use.

Instead, I would like it to return `2,3 3,4 4,5 -> 2,3,3,4,4,5`. I would like each of the puts to be iterated for each of the possible values of number; In this case `1` and `2` are the two possible values of 'number', before moving on to the next puts.

One way to do this is to create two lists, `[2,3,4]` and `[3,4,5]` and then use the `zip` method to combine them like `[2,3,4].zip([3,4,5]) -> [2,3,3,4,4,5]`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`zip` is good. You should also look at `each_cons`:

```
1.9.2p290 :006 > [2,3,4].each_cons(2).to_a
 => [[2, 3], [3, 4]] 
1.9.2p290 :007 > [2,3,4,5,6].each_cons(2).to_a
 => [[2, 3], [3, 4], [4, 5], [5, 6]] 
1.9.2p290 :008 > [2,3,4,5,6].each_cons(3).to_a
 => [[2, 3, 4], [3, 4, 5], [4, 5, 6]]
```

Because `each_cons` returns an Enumerator, you can use a block with it, as mentioned in the documentation for it, or convert it to an array using `to_a` like I did above. That returns the array of arrays, which can be flattened to get a single array:

```
 [2,3,4,5].each_cons(2).to_a.flatten
 => [2, 3, 3, 4, 4, 5]
```

From the `ri` docs:

> Iterates the given block for each array of consecutive  elements.  If no
>   block is given, returns an enumerator.
>
> ```
> e.g.:
>   (1..10).each_cons(3) {|a| p a}
>   # outputs below
>   [1, 2, 3]
>   [2, 3, 4]
>   [3, 4, 5]
>   [4, 5, 6]
>   [5, 6, 7]
>   [6, 7, 8]
>   [7, 8, 9]
>   [8, 9, 10]
> ```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe not the most readable code but you could use inject on the first range to create an array based on the summed up second range.

```
(1..3).inject([]){|m,n| (1..2).each{|i| m<<n+i }; m }
=> [2, 3, 3, 4, 4, 5]
```

This might be a little more readable

```
res=[]
(1..3).each{|r1| (1..2).each{|r2| res<<r1+r2 } }
```

Answer (score -1):

```
[1, 2, 3].each { |i| [1, 2].each { |y| puts i + y  } }
```